# SetHandler seems to be ignored

Tags: apache, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, shibboleth

Installing shibboleth on apache 2 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS.  Actual shib install seems to go fine, so configure the site .conf file to use shibboleth.

When I access https://lib.msu.edu/secure, it is handled by shibboleth (with an appropriate config exception at this stage), but when I access https://lib.msu.edu/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata (or anything else in Shibboleth.sso) it get redirected to php/drupal and never seen by the shibboleth system and gets a 404 error.

My best guess is that apache is not passing the request to shibboleth, but I am not sure why, nor how to debug the situation.  This all worked fine on our test server and we cannot find any configuration differences that explain why.

apache .conf file follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName lib.msu.edu
    ServerAlias library.msu.edu
    ServerAlias [...]
    DocumentRoot [MyValidRoot]

    <Directory [MyValidRoot]>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Location /Shibboleth.sso>
            SetHandler shib
    </Location>
    <Location /secure>
            AuthType shibboleth
            ShibRequireSession On
            Require valid-user
    </Location>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile [validcertpath]
    SSLCertificateKeyFile [validkeypath]
    SSLCertificateChainFile [validIntermediateCertpath]

    SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1
    SSLCipherSuite          [cipherString]
    SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
    SSLCompression          off

    SSLUseStapling          on
    SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 5
    SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off

    Redirect /cgi-bin/ [CGIserver]/cgi-bin/

    # Redirect all requests to lib.msu.edu (except wwwm, for testing mirror)
    <If "! req('Host') in { 'lib.msu.edu', 'wwwm.lib.msu.edu' }">
            Redirect / https://lib.msu.edu/
    </If>

    RewriteEngine On

    # force trailing slash
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=post [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*(?:^|/)[^/\.]+)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

    # redirect .js and .css 404s to tomcat
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js)$
    RewriteCond /var/www/mainweb%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://tomcat.lib.msu.edu/$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you for any help you can give!  We have already spent hours banging our heads on this shibboleth install.

Comment: I see this question has been out for months, with no answer. I have a similar problem... did you find the solution?

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this? Apache via Ubuntu is being a total sod about this exact problem.

Comment: Adambean, we did eventually get it working. However, we have since moved away from Shibboleth and I cannot find the old working config file to tell you what we changed.

Comment: Still facing this issue on aws linux 2 instance with Gunicorn.

Answer (score 0):

On my site, the solution was to add `UseCanonicalName On` to the Apache virtualhost config.

According to the Apache manual, this sets the "SERVER_NAME" (variable usually used by CGI scripts) to the string behind "ServerName". Especially if the virtualhost uses "ServerAlias" a "wrong" name might be communicated to shibboleth.

I assume Shibboleth Module uses the "SERVER_NAME" variable to check/select the  certificate. Make sure the shibboleth certificate uses the Apache configured "ServerName" as "Issuer CN".